# Automatic lowercase renaming -Windows

Tags: windows, rename, bulk

I'm looking for a way to bulk rename some files, letting me decide some specific words which will always go in the case I select. Specifically, I want to be able to tell the program I want all articles, conjugations and prepositions lowercase if they are not at the beginning of the filename.

For example, if in the folder, among the other files, there's the movie "The Assassination Of Jesse James By The Coward Robert Ford", it will be renamed to "The Assassination of Jesse James by the Coward Robert Ford"

Comment: Check [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/65302/is-there-a-way-to-batch-rename-files-to-lowercase?rq=1) and [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line-or-using-a-3rd-party-tool)

Answer (score 0):

Download Offline IMDb Movie List. [Offline Movie List: movies.list.gz](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/misc/movies/database/movies.list.gz)

Search movie name in file `movies.list` and replace movie file name. Goog Luck!

command:

```
findstr /I /B /C:"The Assassination Of Jesse James By The Coward Robert Ford" movies.list
```

Output:

```
The Assassination of Jesse James by the Coward Robert Ford (2007)       2007
```

[IMDb Alternative Interfaces](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces)

[IMDb Non-Commercial Licensing page:](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?usedatasoftware)

Can I use IMDb data in my software?

Limited non-commercial use of IMDb data is allowed, provided the following conditions are met:

1. You agree to all the terms of our copyright/conditions of use statement.Please also note that IMDb reserves the right to withdraw permission to use the data at any time at our discretion.
2. The data must be taken only from the plain text data made available from our FTP sites (see [alternative interfaces](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces) for more details and for links to our FTP servers). You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar online data gathering and extraction tools on our website. If the information/data you want is not present in     the data files available from our FTP sites, it means it's not available for non-commercial usage.
3. The data can only be used for personal and non-commercial use and must not be altered/republished/resold/repurposed to create any kind of online/offline database of    movie information (except for individual personal use). Please refer to the copyright/license information enclosed in each file for further instructions and limitations on allowed usage.
4. You must acknowledge the source of the data by including the following statement:

   **Information courtesy of IMDb
   (http://www.imdb.com).
   Used with permission.**

Answer (score 0):

I use [PFrank](http://www3.telus.net/pfrank/) for things like this. It's regex based, so provided you know/are willing to learn a little bit about regular expressions you can easily set up a bunch of rules to do exactly what you're after.

For instance, set step one to replace all instances of `The` with `the`.
Then use the regular expression `^the` to find instances of `the` at the start of the filename (the `^` qualifier means start of string), and replace that with `The` for step two.

Create additional rules as needed.