# Renaming all files of a particular type to lowercase batch

Tags: batch, rename

In this link [Is there a way to batch rename files to lowercase?](https://superuser.com/q/65302/309481)

there is a command given

```
for /f "Tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /l/b/a-d') do (rename "%%f" "%%f")
```

This works when i want to convert all filenames in a folder to lowercase.

However, is there any way to convert files of only one type (eg .RMT) to lowercase?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing, just add "*.RMT" inside the dir expansion, so:

```
('dir /l/b/a-d')
```

becomes

```
('dir /l/b/a-d *.RMT')
```