# f" "f" was unexpected at this time

Tags: command-line

I was looking at this post:
[Is there a way to batch rename files to lowercase?](https://superuser.com/questions/65302/is-there-a-way-to-batch-rename-files-to-lowercase)

and I tried to use it in a textfile, renaming the extention into .bat, then running it at the directory. But, the title error popped up, and nothing happened. Any guesses on why this is happening?

Comment: check the quotes, it looks that your editor changed them.

Comment: @wmz If you're talking about the recursive version, I tried them both and neither of them worked. EDIT: I see what you mean, but it seems fine to me

Comment: no - in your title there are different types of quotes ('inverted' and 'straight' quotes).  Plus, the version shown in the linked answer should be run directly form command line, not as batch file (if you want to run it from batch, replace `%f` with `%%f`

Comment: @wmz Hm. It says the syntax of the command is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Using the FOR command in a batchfile works slightly different, because batchfiles themselves use %? variables. For that reason the FOR command requires its parameter to be %%? to work.

If you enter FOR /? from a commandline, the help will tell you this as well.

So the following FOR command would be the following in a batch file:

**in cmd:**

```
for %i IN (*.*) DO echo %i
```

**in file.bat:**

```
for %%i IN (*.*) DO echo %%i
```