# How to rename all the files and folders of files in a folder to have lower case names at once?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-rename

I have a folder with a bunch of textures and things that I need to rename to lower case, is there any way to rename all the files and folders of files in this folder to have lower case names at once?
edit: this is different from the similar post because the command from that answer will only do it for one folder at a time, not all the folders in the top folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to batch rename files to lowercase?](https://superuser.com/questions/65302/is-there-a-way-to-batch-rename-files-to-lowercase)

Comment: No, sorry. I already looked at that but that command can only rename the files in a single folder at a time and I have a lot of folders sadly

Comment: Only a simple adaptation is needed. See below.

Comment: I tried all of the commands below but they all return errors and all the files are still in caps

Comment: If you look closely, I think you'll see file names have changed, it's folder names that generate the `Source/Destination` error.

Answer (score 2):

I found this in a comment on the simalar post that at first i thought only renamed things in the foler its executed in. It seems to work

```
 Get-ChildItem "C:\path\to\folder" -recurse | 
  Where {-Not $_.PSIsContainer} | 
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.FullName.ToLower()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this powershell code:

```
Get-childItem "Filepath" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename.tostring().tolower() + $_.extension}
```

This will recursively rename all files and folders in "Filepath" to lower case.

Comment: I tried that in the powershell command line but it just kept saying "Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different."

Answer (score 0):

Based on
[Is there a way to batch rename files to lowercase](https://superuser.com/questions/65302/is-there-a-way-to-batch-rename-files-to-lowercase),
here is a formulation that does files and folders recursively:

```
for /f "Tokens=*" %f in ('dir /l/b/s') do (rename "%f" "%f")
```

Comment: Recursive version: `for /f "Tokens=*" %f in ('dir /l/b/a-d/s') do (rename "%f" "%f")` per comment in that same post since all other answers are showing recursive too.

Comment: I tried that in powershell and cmd and it just returned errors

Comment: What errors? It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:
Verbose, Files

```
$Source = 'c:\TopFolder'
( Get-ChildItem $Source -File -Recurse ) | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.ToLower() }
```

Key-Banger, Files:

```
(gci 'c:\TopFolder' -af -r) | ren -new { $_.Name.ToLower() }
```

For folders, to avoid `Source/Destination` errors, you have to rename to a temp value as an intermediate step. Here's one way:

```
gci -ad -Recurse | %{
$Lower = $_.Name.ToLower()
$_ | ren -new {(Get-Date).Ticks } -passthru | ren -new {$Lower}
}
```

Comment: Um, what is key-banger? I tried the top one in powershell and it just returned errors

Comment: Using aliases to shorten the expression. What sort of error messages? Do any of the names have special characters like `$`, `[`, or `]`?